# OneDrive-Path: Used on a website to serve JSON files

Tags: angular, azure, path, onedrive

I am trying to access a file, which is shared on a public OneDrive folder.

Folder:

> https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiU5zEgMWxPk-xJ4a-DcxiahZNUm?e=KdwzAM

File:

> *Sound*.json

Import:

```
this.http.get<SomeObject[]>('howToUseThePath/_Sound_.json', { responseType: 'json' })
      .subscribe(data => {
        // ...
```

Is that possible, if so, please provide the correct path?

Comment: Have you tried to use the OneDrive file storage API?

Comment: Without using the API?